# Creating custom shape border via css

Tags: css, bootstrap-4

how can i create this shape via css ?

[Example](https://i.stack.imgur.com/eewU9.png)

Comment: SO is not a coding service ... do a small search and try to do it, then get back when you have trouble

Comment: That's the thing i know it's not, i tried looking for it but can't find proper direction where to start, i started with borders but that didnt work out

Comment: so add from where you start so that we know you did an effort or we consider there is 0 effort and you are only looking for a ready-to-use code

Comment: Well i started only from     border-top-left-radius: ; but that cant go in - so i dont really know where to continue or what to search for that fits to my example

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is an example of a paper folding effect achieved via CSS.

The key here is the box shadow which is positioned over the div using `:before`

HTML

```
<div class="note">

</div>
```

CSS

```
.note {
  position: relative;
  width: 30%;
  padding: 1em 1.5em;
  margin: 2em auto;
  color: #fff;
  background: #97C02F;
  overflow: hidden;
}

.note:before {
  content: "";
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  right: 0;
  border-width: 0 16px 16px 0;
  border-style: solid;
  border-color: #fff #fff #658E15 #658E15;
  background: #658E15;
  box-shadow: 0 1px 1px rgba(0,0,0,0.3), -1px 1px 1px rgba(0,0,0,0.2);
}
```

Codepen example https://codepen.io/Washable/pen/BJqMJd

Comment: thank you, i didnt know how to search this exactly, tho i found one similar example this one is way better, thanks!